# Highstock chart not rendered when using load event

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highstock chart, which is loaded with some default data. Then based on the user action(button clicks), I redraw the chart with new data from the server. I have a common function to retrieve the data from the server and I call it from the load event of the chart as well as on the user actions. However, the chart does not get rendered on load. When I try to redraw the chart on some user actions, it renders the chart in the navigation area correctly but not in the main chart area. If I change the StockChart to simple HighChart, the chart renders fine on user clicks but not on load.

Can someone please help? Thanks!!

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){

  // global to allow access to options when dynamically loading series.
  var statsChart;

  // global requestOptions, so that event handlers can just update
  // the specific option instead of building it again.
  var requestOptions = {
    'resolution': 'hourly' // default to an hour
  };

  var chart_options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        renderTo: 'stats-chart-div',
        events:{
            load: updateChartData
        }
    },
    rangeSelector : {
        selected : 1,
        buttons : [{
            type: 'hour',
            count: 6,
            text: '6H'
        }, {
            type: 'day',
            count: 1,
            text: '1D'
        }, {
            type: 'day',
            count: 7,
            text: '1W'
        }, {
            type: 'week',
            count: 4,
            text: '1M'
        }, {
            type: 'month',
            count: 12,
            text: '1Y'
        }]
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Stat Count'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            hourlyButton: {
                x: -150,
                onclick: function () {
                    requestOptions['resolution'] = 'hourly';
                    updateChartData();
                },
                symbol: '',
                text: 'Hourly',
                theme: {
                    'stroke-width': 1,
                    'fill': '#808080',
                    'fill-opacity': 0.75
                },
                tooltip: {
                    text: 'Stats aggregated hourly'
                }
            },
            dailyButton: {
                id: 'daily',
                x: -100,
                onclick: function () {
                    requestOptions['resolution'] = 'daily';
                    updateChartData();
                },
                symbol: '',
                text: 'Daily',
                theme: {
                    'stroke-width': 1,
                    'fill': '#808080',
                    'fill-opacity': 0.75
                }
            },
            weeklyButton: {
                x: -40,
                onclick: function () {
                    requestOptions['resolution'] = 'weekly';
                    updateChartData();
                },
                symbol: '',
                text: 'Weekly',
                theme: {
                    'stroke-width': 1,
                    'fill': '#808080',
                    'fill-opacity': 0.75
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series : [
        {
            name: 'Average Stats',
            id: 'avg-stats',
            data: []
        }
    ]
  };
  var updateChartData = function() {
      fetchData(function(data){
         var series = statsChart.get('avg-stats');
         if (series) {
             series.setData(data['avg_stats'], false);
         }
         statsChart.redraw();
      }
  };

  var fetchData = function(callback) {
      $.getJSON('/index.php/getStats',
                requestOptions,
                function(data) {
                    statsData = JSON.parse(data.results);
                    callback(statsData);
                }
      );
  }
  statsChart = new Highcharts.StockChart(chart_options);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in using `startsChart` variable - it's not assigned in load event. Change:

```
var updateChartData = function() {
  var sChart = this;
  fetchData(function(data){
     var series = sChart.get('avg-stats');
     if (series) {
         series.setData(data['avg_stats'], false);
     }
     sChart.redraw();
  }
};
```

Comment: That didn't help. I got the highcharts error 13 but I see the chart axes, legend and the exporting buttons. Also, when the updateChartData is called again I get Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'get'. I also tried changing it to this.statsChart and then I didn't see the typeError but I still see the highchart error 13. I would guess if the renderTo is not configured properly, I would not see any chart attributes at all.

Comment: The Highchart error 13 was typo on my part. The chart still does not render.I also want to add that with my original code I would see the chart in the navigation area but not the main chart area but the load event doesn't work at all.

Comment: Any other errors? Do you have live site with that error? For me it's obvious it's not Highcharts issue.

Comment: No other errors. Its not on a public site so I can't really share it. I have been able to workaround this problem by a different approach although i don't really like it much. I don't used the load event now and what i have done is make an explicit call to fetchdata function on document ready and initialize the chart options and the chart inside the callback for that method.

Comment: Something like in this demo: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/ ? It's very strange. You can try to reproduce error on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround this problem by using the following code. This seems like a hack to me and I would appreciate if someone can suggest a better solution.

```
$(function(){

  // global to allow access to options when dynamically loading series.
  var statsChart;

  // global requestOptions, so that event handlers can just update
  // the specific option instead of building it again.
  var requestOptions = {
    'resolution': 'hourly' // default to an hour
  };

  var fetchData = function(callback) {
    $.getJSON('/index.php/getStats',
            requestOptions,
            function(data) {
                statsData = JSON.parse(data.results);
                callback(statsData);
            }
     );
  };

  var updateChartData = function() {
    fetchData(function(data){
       var series = statsChart.get('avg-stats');
       if (series) {
         series.setData(data['avg_stats'], false);
       }
       statsChart.redraw();
    }
  };

  fetchData(function(data){
     var chart_options = {
       chart: {
       type: 'spline',
       renderTo: 'stats-chart-div',
       },
       rangeSelector : {
         selected : 1,
         buttons : [{
           type: 'hour',
           count: 6,
           text: '6H'
       }, {
         type: 'day',
         count: 1,
         text: '1D'
       }, {
         type: 'day',
         count: 7,
         text: '1W'
       }, {
         type: 'week',
         count: 4,
         text: '1M'
       }, {
         type: 'month',
         count: 12,
         text: '1Y'
      }]
     },
     xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime'
     },
     yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Stat Count'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: true,
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    exporting: {
      buttons: {
        hourlyButton: {
            x: -150,
            onclick: function () {
                requestOptions['resolution'] = 'hourly';
                updateChartData();
            },
            symbol: '',
            text: 'Hourly',
            theme: {
                'stroke-width': 1,
                'fill': '#808080',
                'fill-opacity': 0.75
            },
            tooltip: {
                text: 'Stats aggregated hourly'
            }
        },
        dailyButton: {
            id: 'daily',
            x: -100,
            onclick: function () {
                requestOptions['resolution'] = 'daily';
                updateChartData();
            },
            symbol: '',
            text: 'Daily',
            theme: {
                'stroke-width': 1,
                'fill': '#808080',
                'fill-opacity': 0.75
            }
        },
        weeklyButton: {
            x: -40,
            onclick: function () {
                requestOptions['resolution'] = 'weekly';
                updateChartData();
            },
            symbol: '',
            text: 'Weekly',
            theme: {
                'stroke-width': 1,
                'fill': '#808080',
                'fill-opacity': 0.75
            }
        }
      }
    },
    series : [
       {
        name: 'Average Stats',
        id: 'avg-stats',
        data: data['avg_stats']
      }
    ]
   };

   statsChart = new Highcharts.StockChart(chart_options);
  });
}
```